# DB2 Developer Extension v2.1.2 error: "Failed to find keytar" and "Error running command connectionProvider.add"

Tags: visual-studio-code, plugins, db2, developer-tools

I have installed the "**IBM Db2 for z/OS Developer Extension**" V2.1.2 on Visual Studio Code V1.83.0.
With the previous version I had no problem and was able to configure and use the plugin.
With this new version I got the following error messages and all my configuration was deleted

*- Failed to find keytar module for managing passwords.*

*- Error running command connectionProvider.add: command 'connectionProvider.add' not found. This is likely caused by the extension that contributes connectionProvider.add.*

Please could you help me to understand what's happening?

Answer (score 0):

As for the Keytar error, this is probably because Keytar is deprecated in VS Code and is no longer distributed as part of VS Code installations. See https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_83#_keytar-removed-from-vs-code. You should probably raise an issue ticket to your extension's maintainer about this (please search first to see if an issue ticket about it has already been raised to them). Actually, the maintainers to this extension have already been notified about this in this issue ticket: [Keytar Migration Plan #102](https://github.com/IBM/db2forzosdeveloperextension-about/issues/102), and they've addressed the removal in version 2.1.3 of their extension.

As for the other error, I don't know. It could be a knock-on error caused by the keytar error, or something different.

Comment: If anyone reading this ends up raising an issue ticket like I suggested, please either comment here with the link to the issue ticket, or notify me in the issue ticket with "@starball5" and a link to this Stack Overflow post so I can update it.